# Restcomm conference management

Tags: restcomm

while checking for conferences through the api i get back a huge list with all the conference that were created.
Is there any way to clear them up (delete old conferences)?
didnt find anything in the api definition.
Thx in advance,

Comment: Hi Nicholas, 

Could you please share which version you're running, on what platform and some steps to reproduce the issue you're facing?
Also, it would help to know which API docs you're referencing ;) Thanks

Comment: Hello I am using Restcomm-Connect 8.2.1.GA. Steps to reproduce are quite simple just call a few conferences.My Questing is if there is a way to get only the active calls everytime i fire an api call to retrieve conference list, not everything since server started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you mention [supervisorAPI](https://www.restcomm.com/docs/connect/api/monitoring-service.html#monitoring)

There are two parts returned there, the "real time" and the "accumulated" metrics. The real-time metrics should be close to your requirements, since active calls should be present in real-time metrics.

If you are looking for specific Conferences using the [conferencesAPI](https://www.restcomm.com/docs/connect/api/conferences-api.html#conferenceapi), you may introduce query parameters in the url, to filter the results. These includes:

- "PageSize"
- "Page"
- "Status"
- "DateCreated"
- "DateUpdated"
- "FriendlyName"

In your case you may play with Status query param, and see if that meets your requirements.

Regarding cleaning, these CDR records are not meant to be removed, as they represent basic accounting information. Currently there are no requirements on removing CDRs from the REST API (of course nothing prevents from removing at the Database level).

Comment: hello Jaime,i am actually referring to the conference management   
   api as found in  restcomm/2012-04-24/Accounts/AC7f947b4e303121a700ff20342367c69d/Conferences.json